# Laptop says “reset system” after trying to dualboot

Tags: boot, 21.10, reset

I have set up a dual-boot system of windows 11 and ubuntu 21.10 on my laptop.  After installation it said that it succeeded. When rebooting it says "reset system" and keeps repeating that message.

Any fixes without losing my windows?

Comment: Try entering the BIOS and look for a setting that sounds like "reset to factory" or "reset to defaults". Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema well, im not talking about my bios, this didnt happen before i install ubuntu, it happened after.

Comment: Yes, but it sounds like you're not even getting to the BIOS splash screen, yes?

Comment: @heynnema i am, i can enter the bios, its an hp laptop btw, but i can enter the bios and stuff, i just cant get into my windows.

Comment: Does "I am" mean that you DO see the BIOS splash screen? Try this... power off, power on, as soon as you see the BIOS splash screen, mash the ESC key a few times and see if you get to the GRUB menu.

Comment: @heynnema that doesnt bring up the grub ofc thats the button for my bios, im now in my windows but i had to choose the efi file manually, im gonna search for smth so i can make grub appear and stuff

Comment: In the BIOS, check your UEFI boot order, and make sure that Ubuntu is selected. Then reboot.

Comment: There isnt a ubuntu, its only usb, pcie sdd hard drive, os boot mgr, sdc, optica disk, generic usb, customized boot, ethernet

Comment: Do any of those point to a /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file?

Comment: @heynnema well, i have now set it to automatically boot to windows, but if i want to boot to grub, it just says reset system again.

Comment: You didn't exactly answer my last question. How are you selecting *"if I want to boot to GRUB"*?

Comment: @heynnema i meant, when i boot to grub it doesnt boot to grub, just to ubuntu. And its not showing grub.

Comment: You're still not being entirely clear. How are you *"boot to GRUB"*, and does Ubuntu actually boot up? If you select "os boot mgr", what do you get?

Comment: @heynnema so, im NOT able to boot to grub, if i use my bios to manually select the efi file i can boot up to windows and ubuntu just fine, but my problem now is i cant boot to grub.

Comment: It sounds like GRUB didn't get installed correctly. Boot into Ubuntu, and in the `terminal` type `sudo update-grub`, then `reboot`.

Comment: @heynnema that didnt work

Comment: Boot into Ubuntu again, and in `terminal` type `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard.

Comment: Is your BIOS set to UEFI mode, or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)